# How use redux without requirejs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to use Redux with reactjs and it's failing with the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I'm trying to include react and redux like this:

*In index.html head tag*

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.0/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.16/browser.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="/react-redux.min.js"></script>
```

But when I do this (from the redux website):

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
```

I get the error and if I don't have that statement, then I get an error that `createStore` doesn't exist when I try to use it.

How can I use redux + react without requirejs?

Comment: `Redux.createStore` ???

Answer (score 0):

The website is using ES6 syntax, which is not implemented in major browsers today. You need to add a compile step using babel, which would output all of your javascript into one bundle.js file, including your code, react, redux, and all other dependencies.

if you want to work with react and redux, it makes more sense to learn how to set up a workflow to use ES6 syntax. You could consider using create-react-app as a base, and add redux support from there:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app newReduxApp
npm install --save redux
npm start
```

Then head into App.js and add the createStore. Because create-react-app has set up ES6 compilation for you using babel, you will be able to use ES6 syntax.

If you would prefer to not use ES6 syntax, you won't be able to use a lot of the documentation on the web without first changing it to ES5 syntax. Using http://redux.js.org/docs/api/ as a reference, your line would be:

```
var createStore = Redux.createStore
```

Comment: I already use babel-cli to compile during the build, so that's not the issue. The line becomes `var _redux = require( "redux" )`

Comment: I'm confused - are you building or using the files from the CDN?

Comment: If you have your heart set on using the files from the CDN, I probably can't help you, since I've never really set that up. If you're willing to try the create-react-app approach above, you may have more luck.

Comment: Right, now I get it. You're embedding your redux code in a script tag or something, right? So presumably the redux.min.js you've included exports redux onto the window object as `window.Redux`. So that means you can just leave out the `import { createStore } from 'redux'` line altogether and use `window.Redux.createStore` instead

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `browserify` grunt task to bundle the compiled js by babel. `browserify` contains a small CommonJS require module, which does the `required` method.

Here is my grunt task for `browserify`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  var files = {
    '.tmp/public/js/z/bundle-<%= githash.main.hash %>.js': ['assets/js/**/*.jsx']
  };

  grunt.config.set('browserify', {
    dist: {
      options: {
        transform: [['babelify', {presets: ['airbnb']}]]
      },
      files: files,
    },
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
};
```

Besides, you should add following dev dependencies to you package.json.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-airbnb": "^2.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "grunt-browserify": "^5.0.0"
}
```